# Cell with NSAttributedString makes the scrolling of UITableView slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, tableview, nsattributedstring

I have a table view that contains multiple kinds of cells. One of them is a cell with a TextView and in this text view, I have to render an `NSAttributedString` from data. This has to be done on the main Thread according to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-initwithdata):

> The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread (that is, the options dictionary includes NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute with a value of NSHTMLTextDocumentType). It will try to synchronize with the main thread, fail, and time out. Calling it from the main thread works (but can still time out if the HTML contains references to external resources, which should be avoided at all costs). The HTML import mechanism is meant for implementing something like markdown (that is, text styles, colors, and so on), not for general HTML import.

but rendering in this way will make lags on the scrolling of the table view and also will mess with auto layout. This is my code inside my cell.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style=\"font-family:%@; font-size:%dpx; color:#08080d;\">%@</div>",fontNameBase, 16,txt];
    htmlString = [Utility replaceHtmlCodeEntities:htmlString];
    NSData* tempData = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:tempData  options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    self.textViewMsg.attributedText = txt;
});
```

I scroll my tableView like this:

```
-(void)reloadAndScroll{
    [self.tableChat reloadData];

    long lastRowNumber = [_tableChat numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;
    if (lastRowNumber > 0) {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
        [_tableChat scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath        
        atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Are there any other ways to create an Attributed string without these problems?

Comment: What if you create attributed string in background thread and then render that string into UITextView in main thread, the problem will still exist? Please go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: @Rameez can you explain this approach? I tried to use 'performSelectorInBackground' but I encountered a crash.

Comment: What is the description of that crash?

Comment: @Rameez Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'

Comment: Alright. It means all your code must be on main thread. So i've a quick suggestion for you. Don't create attributed string every time. Once attributed string is created, store that string into your model. So when next time table view will reload your cell, pick that already created string from your model.

Comment: Why don’t you use initwithhtml:documentAttributes:? No apparent restrictions on threads.

Comment: @Rameez it's a table for the chat so for new messages I have to render immediately.

Comment: @taratandel No problem. You just have to maintain a flag in your model for your message either its attributed string is already created or not. If message's attributed string is already created then pick from your model otherwise create that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think u have to create the Attributed String in your Model class, So that table view cell for row method does not create a new Attributed string on scrolling,Hope It well help you out, Thanks

```
+(AttributedModel *)methodToGetAttributedDetail :(NSString *)txt {

    AttributedModel *objModel = [[AttributedModel alloc] init];

   NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style=\"font-family:%@; font-size:%dpx; color:#08080d;\">%@</div>",fontNameBase, 16,txt];
   htmlString = [Utility replaceHtmlCodeEntities:htmlString];
   NSData* tempData = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
   NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:tempData  options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

   objModel.attributedString  = attributedString;

   return objModel;
}
```

Use this model value in CellforRow Method of table view

Comment: Do you mean `modal` or `model`?

Comment: Yeah Definately , Model same from MVC approach, Thanks

Comment: why should I return my whole model ? is there any specific reason that you did that?

Comment: Nops, not necessary i just showing the modular way if you have some other information along with this attributed string .

Comment: I tried your approach but I get a crash about CFRunloop

Comment: Can you please share the code , So i can debug at my end, Thanks