# How to display HTML content in UITextview in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

From my response, I am getting the HTML tags with some strings. I am displaying the dynamic contents in my table view. I've converted HTML tags and displaying in the table view. But the problem is, **facing the table view flickering issue heavily and it affects the performance also**.
Can you please suggest me, if there is any other way to improve the performance.
I am thinking to add the HTML tags manually and replace the tags based on the response. Bcoz I don't want to affect my performance. please advice.

Eg: How to get the  **Customer Support** ?.

The below code is for converting the html code,

```
    var encryptData : String = inputString
    if inputString.contains("<") {
        encryptData = inputString.htmlToString // Converting HTML to text

    }
    else { return  encryptData } // Normal string


extension String {
var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}
var htmlToString: String {
    return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Approach 
[Cell with NSAttributedString makes the scrolling of UITableView slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210526/cell-with-nsattributedstring-makes-the-scrolling-of-uitableview-slow/59212520?noredirect=1#comment104647209_59212520)

It will help you out for table view flickering. Thanks