# IOS 13 UITextView with Html Attributed String embedded in UITableViewCell scrolling lag

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, nsmutableattributedstring

In IOS 12 the scrolling of `UITableView` is smooth without lag even when html string contains image but in IOS 13 `UITableView` scrolling becomes laggy. Already try `shouldresterizing = true` but doesn't solve the problem. Simulator and Device are the same results.

```swift
class ProductTextViewCell:UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        textView.text = "-"
        textView.dataDetectorTypes = .all
    }
    func set(str:String) {
        print(str)

        if let attributed = str.html2AttributedString {
            let mutable = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributed)
            self.textView.attributedText = mutable

            mutable.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.attachment, in: NSMakeRange(0, attributed.length), options: .init(rawValue: 0), using: { (value, range, stop) in

                if let attachement = value as? NSTextAttachment {
                    if let image = attachement.image(forBounds: attachement.bounds, textContainer: NSTextContainer(), characterIndex: range.location) {
                        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

                        let max = screenSize.width - 20
                        print(max)
                        print(image.size.width)
                        if image.size.width > max {
                            let scale = image.size.height / image.size.width
                            attachement.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: max, height: max * scale)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            self.textView.attributedText = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210526/cell-with-nsattributedstring-makes-the-scrolling-of-uitableview-slow/59212520?noredirect=1#comment104647209_59212520) . The solution is change string to attributedText before set into tableView (should apply this change when parse data to model)